# How to make event only true for one element in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have vue event attached to elements that are looped.

I'm having challenge trying display CRUD action on an item, instead, all the looped items display their individual CRUD

How can I make it unique to an element? any vue event modifier for this?

Below is my code

```
<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light" v-on:mouseenter="showIcons"><i class="material-icons">list</i></a>
            <div v-if="showButtons">
                <ul>
                    <li>Edit</li>
                    <li>Delete</li>
                    <li>Stop</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The showIcons method below

```
showIcons: function () {
            this.showButtons = true
        }
```

Comment: what unique element?

Comment: I want when I hover on one element, let only that event be fired, not firing the whole iterated elements @samayo

Answer (score 2):

since you are binding `showButtons` property to all your looped items, when you mouse over an item the`showButtons`is toggled true and all the items bound to `showButtons` are displayed.

So you need to use a unique identifier to decide whether the buttons for an item should be displayed or not.

You might be looping using `v-for` so you can make use of index.

**template**

```
<div v-for="(item , index)">
            <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light" v-on:mouseenter="showIcons(index)"><i class="material-icons">list</i></a>
                <div v-if="currentlyShowing === index">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Edit</li>
                        <li>Delete</li>
                        <li>Stop</li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
</div>
```

**script**

```
data(){
    return{
        currentlyShowing: null
    }
},
methods:{
    showIcons: function (index) {
        this.showButtons = true
        this.currentlyShowing = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but how can I implement it with vue show. I just refactored the code. can I parse in the index to show? Thanks